# Weird Lines on Monitor Scrolling by - Interference?

Tags: display, hardware-failure, vga, lcd

I have a LCD VGA connected monitor attached to my desktop computer.  It works great.  So, in the same room, on a different outlet and on the other side of the room, I plugged in a power-strip.  Now my monitor shows a bunch of weird squiggles passing repeatedly down my monitor screen.  I assume this is some kind of electrical interference showing up.  Aside from unplugging the power-strip and not using it, is there something else I can do or buy to resolve this issue?  Do power-strips have some kind of mechanism to prevent interference?  I assume these weird squiggly lines hurt my monitor.

Thanks

Comment: What is plugged in to that power strip? If it is a high current device that would cause the lines on the screen as the voltage is dropping on the circuit. The best solution for this is get rid of VGA - it is analog and old technology. Use HDMI, DVI, or DV Port - all digital and mostly impervious to interference.

Comment: I only had a laptop plugged into the powerstrip.  Anyway, I have an electrician coming because the power keeps going off in the room.

Comment: Good idea. Doesn't sound like anything to mess around with.